# S3 Cross account access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, amazon-emr

I have a scenario given in the following example: [Example 4: Bucket owner granting cross-account permission to objects it does not own](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example4.html).

I am able to make it work by following this example.
In this they created a user and did this:

```
aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::accountA-ID:role/examplerole \
--profile AccountCDave --role-session-name test
```

to create session. Now I have the following questions.

- Do we really need to create a user and assume role like we did in this example?
- How can we do it with root user?
- Can we assume it in role like EMR_DefaultRole ? If yes, How it will work then?
- Will it work auto for the EMR jobs or do I need to create session in EMR Jobs?

Comment: What is your _actual_ use-case? It sounds like you would like jobs running on Amazon EMR to have access to a bucket in a different account -- is that correct?

Comment: Correct. That's my use case. I have notifications which have different buckets. So I don't want to  assume role in code for different buckets. Is there a way where I can do a pre-config and I am good to go.

Comment: What do you mean by "notifications which have different buckets"? Is a script on EMR accessing that data, or are you wanting those buckets to trigger something?

Comment: Its like I have many different buckets from which I have to read. I want to get objects from these buckets. and this whole thing running on EMR

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method would be:

- In the **EMR_DefaultRole** (or whichever role is being used by EMR), grant sufficient access to access the S3 buckets in the other accounts. For example, grant `s3:GetObject` on all buckets. While this is not sufficient for such access, it is still needed.
- In each of the buckets in the other accounts, add a **Bucket Policy** that grants the EMR role (referenced by ARN) access to the bucket. It will probably need `GetObject` and `ListBucket` permission.

This way, there is no need to assume any roles. Instead, the Role being used by EMR is granted permission to access each bucket.

See: [Bucket policy examples - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-bucket-policies.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer John, but the bucket objects are owned by some other account(which I don't have access) as I mentioned the example 4 scenario.